# Loading RDF File to Hbase

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, apache-jena

i am trying to load the contents of an RDF File (Subject,Predicate,Object) to a table in HBase. 
So far i cannot understand how the contents of the file can be passed to the map method of the mapper class and to be stored in Hbase.
Please provide your answers with code in order to understand your solution better.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

there is a way ((RDF4J)), you can fill HBASE with RDF data.